# Xamarin.Android Cannot use recorded custom sound for push notifications in Android 10 (Q)

Tags: android, xamarin, push-notification

This used to work, record a sound in order to use for the custom sound for a push notification channel. Now it does not anymore.
What changed please, why would this not work anymore, there is no sound when notification comes in?

In order to use a recorded sound for push notifications, I used to copy it to external storage from where it can be accessed at runtime like this:

the path for an external path was like this:

> /storage/emulated/0/customNotificationSoundRecording.wav

Here is the full code, first record the sound:

```
private async Task RecordAudio()
        {
            buttonSave.IsEnabled = false;
            try
            {
                if (!recorder.IsRecording)
                {                
                    buttonRecord.IsEnabled = false;
                    buttonPlay.IsEnabled = false;               

                    // only if ios
                    if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.iOS)
                        DependencyService.Get<IAudioService>().PrepareRecording();


                    Increment = 1 / (double)AppConstants.MAX_RECORD_TIME;
                    Set_Timer();

                    var recordTask = await recorder.StartRecording();

                    buttonRecord.Text = "Stop";
                    buttonRecord.IsEnabled = true;

                    // get the recorded file
                    var recordedAudioFile = await recordTask;
                    // isRecording = false;                  

                    if (recordedAudioFile != null)
                    {
                        // first save the file from cache to AppData
                        var recordingFileDestinationPath = Path.Combine(FileSystem.AppDataDirectory, AppConstants.CUSTOM_ALERT_FILENAME);                     

                        //if (File.Exists(recordingFileDestinationPath))
                        if (CustomAlertSoundExists(recordingFileDestinationPath))
                        {
                            File.Delete(recordingFileDestinationPath);
                        }

                        File.Copy(recordedAudioFile, recordingFileDestinationPath);                     

                        Preferences.Set(AppConstants.CUSTOM_RECORDING_EXISTS_KEY, true);

                        if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.iOS)
                        {
                            DependencyService.Get<IGroupUserPrefs>().SetBoolValueForKey("isCustomAlert", true);
                        }

                        buttonSave.IsEnabled = true;
                    }

                    if (secondsElapsed >= AppConstants.MAX_RECORD_TIME)
                    {
                        Preferences.Set(AppConstants.RECORDING_LENGTH_SECONDS_KEY, secondsElapsed);
                        secondsElapsed = 0;
                        Reset_Timer();
                    }

                    buttonRecord.Text = "Record";
                    buttonPlay.IsEnabled = true;

                }
                else // stop button clicked
                {                                  

                    buttonRecord.IsEnabled = false;

                    await recorder.StopRecording();
                    buttonSave.IsEnabled = true;

                    // isRecording = false;

                    Reset_Timer();

                    // save last recording length in seconds
                    Preferences.Set(AppConstants.RECORDING_LENGTH_SECONDS_KEY, secondsElapsed);

                    //reset seconds elapsed 
                    secondsElapsed = 0;

                    buttonRecord.IsEnabled = true;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

And then copy the recording to external storage, used to be that its the only location from where it can be used for push notification sound:

```
public async void CopyRecordingToExternalStorage(string filePath)
        {
            var recordingFileExternalPath = Path.Combine(Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.Path, AppConstants.CUSTOM_ALERT_FILENAME);

             // made some other attempts with different paths.
            // var recordingFileExternalPath = Path.Combine(FileSystem.AppDataDirectory, AppConstants.CUSTOM_ALERT_FILENAME);
            //var recordingFileExternalPath = Path.Combine(Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryAlarms).AbsolutePath, AppConstants.CUSTOM_ALERT_FILENAME);

            var storageStatus = await CrossPermissions.Current.CheckPermissionStatusAsync(Plugin.Permissions.Abstractions.Permission.Storage);

            if (storageStatus != Plugin.Permissions.Abstractions.PermissionStatus.Granted)
            {
                var results = await CrossPermissions.Current.RequestPermissionsAsync(new[] { Plugin.Permissions.Abstractions.Permission.Storage });
                storageStatus = results[Plugin.Permissions.Abstractions.Permission.Storage];
            }

            if (storageStatus == Plugin.Permissions.Abstractions.PermissionStatus.Granted)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (File.Exists(recordingFileExternalPath))  // if file exists already in external storage
                    {
                        File.Delete(recordingFileExternalPath); // erase the file
                    }

                    File.Copy(filePath, recordingFileExternalPath); // and overwrite with new one
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                UserDialogs.Instance.Alert("Permission to write to External Storage denied, cannot save settings.", "Permission Denied", "Ok");
            }             
        }
```

And then I would create a channel with that sound like this:

```
private void createCustomNotificationChannel()
        {
            try
            {
                // the custom channel
                var urgentChannelName = GetString(Resource.String.noti_chan_custom);
                var customChannelDescription = GetString(Resource.String.noti_chan_custom_description);

                long[] customVibrationPattern = { 100, 30, 100, 30, 100, 200, 200, 30, 200, 30, 200, 200, 100, 30, 100, 30, 100, 100, 30, 100, 30, 100, 200, 200, 30, 200, 30, 200, 200, 100, 30, 100, 30, 100 };

                // Creating an Audio Attribute
                var alarmAttributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                    .SetContentType(AudioContentType.Sonification)
                    .SetUsage(AudioUsageKind.Notification).Build();

                var alarmSourcePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.Path, AppConstants.CUSTOM_ALERT_FILENAME);

                 // also tried here with other paths
                // var alarmSourcePath = Path.Combine(FileSystem.AppDataDirectory, AppConstants.CUSTOM_ALERT_FILENAME);
                // var alarmSourcePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryAlarms).AbsolutePath, AppConstants.CUSTOM_ALERT_FILENAME);

                var urgentAlarmUri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse(alarmSourcePath);

                // checking here if file exists after voice recording and
                //  the bool is true
                bool soundFileExists = File.Exists(alarmSourcePath);

                var chan3 = new NotificationChannel(TERTIARY_CHANNEL_ID, urgentChannelName, NotificationImportance.High)
                {
                    Description = customChannelDescription
                };

                // set the urgent channel properties
                chan3.EnableLights(true);
                chan3.LightColor = Android.Graphics.Color.Red;
                chan3.SetSound(urgentAlarmUri, alarmAttributes);
                chan3.EnableVibration(true);
                chan3.SetVibrationPattern(customVibrationPattern);
                chan3.SetBypassDnd(true);
                chan3.LockscreenVisibility = NotificationVisibility.Public;

                var manager = (NotificationManager)GetSystemService(NotificationService);

                // create chan1  which is the urgent notifications channel
                manager.CreateNotificationChannel(chan3);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To give users more control over their files and to limit file clutter, apps targeting Android 10 (API level 29) and higher are given scoped access into an external storage device, or scoped storage, by default. Such apps can see only their app-specific directory—accessed using `Context.getExternalFilesDir()`—and specific types of media. It's a best practice to use scoped storage unless your app needs access to a file that doesn't reside in either the app-specific directory or the `MediaStore`.you could refer to [Manage scoped external storage access](https://developer.android.google.cn/training/data-storage/files/external-scoped).

if you don't want change,you want to stick With What Worked Before.

For Android Q ,you could try to add `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` to your `<application>` element in the manifest.

Comment: Zhu thanks for that, I came across that as well. I tried adding "android:reguestLegacyExternalStorage="true"" to application tag in manifest but I got an error when building in Visual Studio 2019 saying it cannot find that instruction. As for using MediaStore I didnt try that yet, but will look into it.

Comment: @RazvanEmil have you set the `Target Framework version` to Android 10.0 ?

Comment: Zhu, I was actually just working on this right now. Previously I didnt set the target to Android 10, but now I did. Even with the  android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" to your <application> element in the manifest it does not work for me still. 
I did update the storage save location to this string externalDirPath = CrossCurrentActivity.Current.AppContext.GetExternalFilesDir(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryNotifications).AbsolutePath;
            string recordingFileExternalPath = Path.Combine(externalDirPath, AppConstants.CUSTOM_ALERT_FILENAME); As is, still not working, any idea?

Comment: Zhu Honestly I do not know how to use the MediaStore and I can't find a clear documentation on it. How do I save a file in there, and how do I retrieve when creating a channel for push notifications? Maybe there is an issue because I am using a wav file? Also I thought the code above in previous comment already stores to the MediaStore?!

Comment: @RazvanEmil it' my mistake,if your  App with lower targetSdkVersion values default to opting into legacy storage and would need `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="false" ` to opt out

Comment: Right now I am targeting Android 10 in Visual Studio but from the Google channel not Microsoft (and in Visual studio in brackets next to channel name it says(not supported) for Android Q even though i can install, and from Microsoft channel only up to Android 9. Not sure what that means.So I cant target Android 10 from the google channel in VS 2019 Tools/AndroidSDK? So targeting ANdroid 10, I did add android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" like I mentioned and same result, but only tried with saving custom sound to external Directory.Notifications, not working as of now.

Comment: @RazvanEmil yes,you should install Android 10 from google channel,and i could set it wo target framework version ,i did see the notice(not supported for Android Q),maybe you could try to set the wav file to Resources/Raw  first,and see if it work on Android Q,make sure the wav works on Android Q first